# Command line execution of javascript:document.click.submit()

Tags: javascript, command-line-interface

I've searched, and I'm not convinced I've found what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to bypass having to open up a webpage just to click a link every 48 hours and instead just run a quick command from a CLI client. In the past, the page was .php, and I was able to pass on parameters in the url to simulate clicking that button. Now, the href link is: javascript:document.click.submit().

Is there a way to execute that submit from a command line? It'd be great if I could do it from Lua using LuaSocket, but I'm open to other options as well.

Comment: Depending on level of effort vs. future proofing trade off, you might consider using Selenium. To make it easy as pie, use the Selenium IDE to "record" the click one time and automate that recorded script every day via cron or other scheduler. https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/

Comment: I'll have to look into this, then. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, clicking the button sends some sort of request to a server. You should be able to use the network features in browser developer tools to capture what is being sent to the server. Depending on what the site is doing and how securely it is doing it, you may be able to emulate it with any program that can do http requests.

Comment: Might run into CORs issue though.

Comment: I've never noticed the Network tab before, so I'll take a look at that, but it'll be a matter of understanding and actually processing the information, too. Thanks for your answer!